# How to read bulk or incremental from delta table for Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

We would like to achieve bulk and incremental read data from delta table. so that we are using spark.table("tablename") to read the data. this is fine for us and read bulk data from table. there is another one requirement which we needs to read the data second time spark.table("tableName"), the data should be read the new changes or updated data from delta table.

```
df = spark.table("tablename")  // bulk read data from table
```

we would like to know the incremental read data solution, kindly help.

Comment: Check Delta stream source - https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html

Comment: we are expecting pyspark with spark.table API

Answer (score 1):

For this case you need to enable the [changedatafeed](https://docs.delta.io/2.0.0/delta-change-data-feed.html#enable-change-data-feed) property on your delta table.

- enable this property on your delta table `delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true`

Then read your delta table by using `.readStream()` will give you the new changes that been done starting from the version mentioned.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name STRING, age INT) TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)")
spark.sql("insert into student values(1,'a',20),(2,'b',30)")

# version as ints or longs
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .table("student")
```

https://docs.delta.io/2.0.0/delta-change-data-feed.html#enable-change-data-feed

Comment: the source table we can't change any properties, is it possible other then any alternative solutions. kindly helps because the source table we have timestamp, is it possible to compare to check data changes ?

Comment: Hi, I tried above the examples, is it required .readStream() function find the new changes. as per document spark.read enough right?

Comment: also if I use .readStream function to try to display(df), i am getting as below error
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public static java.lang.String com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DisplayHelper.getStreamName() is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DisplayHelper

Comment: hi, is it possible to use anytimestamp manner to do the incremental load in ADB ?